# Limit total quantity of products in WooCommerce group product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add a fixed quantity of the products based on the selected bundle. I was wondering if it is possible and how would I be able to do that?

I have a group product here https://anthonya68.sg-host.com/product/make-your-own-box/, I want to set a fixed total quantity of the products before they can add the bundle to the cart.

Other question:
– How can I set a fixed price for a group product?

Thanks.